# Google App Engine: Is there any security concern with giving away datastore urlsafe entity keys in an API?

Tags: api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to give out anonymous IDs to certain entities in a public token-based API.

Is there any reason I shouldn't be using the urlsafe string of entity keys for that, since they are already anonymized (at least in my case, where I’m not using my own data to construct the key?

Google App Engine and the Datastore are considered safe as long as I'm not handing anyone the key, which I'm not, right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One of their [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/keyclass) says ....*The urlsafe keyword parameter uses a websafe-base64-encoded serialized reference **but it's best to think of it as just an opaque** unique string*.... I think this is what you're referring to when you say it is anonymized
2. But a subsequent [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/keyclass) says ....The string representation of a key looks cryptic, but is not encrypted! **It can be converted back to the raw key data, both kind and identifier**. If you don't want to expose this data to your users (and allow them to easily guess other entities' keys), then encrypt these strings or use something else....

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the key yourself via [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) - usually there is no risk in giving it away.

The *huge risk* is in taking an urlsafe entity keys as parameters and using them to read from the datastore. An attacker can trick your application in reading arbitrary data from your datastore project. This is to my knowledge nowhere documented.

So basically, any variant of this is a no-go in a web server:

```
def get(params):
    data = datastore.get(urlsavedeccode(params.key))
    return data
```

Any key supplied from the outside should be never used with the datastore since you can not be shure you are reading the `kind` / path you are expecting. This is basically the same scope of risk as [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).